# Transmit phone line signal through the house using powerline-ethernet adapters

Tags: wireless-router, ethernet, powerline-networking

I have a wifi router at home but the place where I want to install it is far from where I have a phone line, which I need to get the ADSL signal.
I have 2 powerline-ethernet adapters, similar to [these ones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0783QH1BH).

Can I use the powerline-ethernet adapters to get the ADSL signal (transmitted through the phone line) to connect to the wifi router?

I mean, at one end I would adapt the phone jack to an ethernet jack and connect it to powerline adapter A. At the other end, I would adapt the ethernet jack, from powerline adapter B, into a phone jack and connect it into the wifi router.

This would be done through the powerline of the same apartment (my own house). 
Would this be possible?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: You said absolutely nothing about ADSL.  You just mentioned a phone line.  However, that still is not a feature of PowerLine, both buildings would have to be on the same circuit for PowerLine to even work anyways.  The only thing you can do is connect both adapters using Ethernet, with one end connected to your ADSL modem.  However, both buildings have to be on the same circuit, which I assume is not the case (that would be extremely strange if that’s the case)

Comment: @DavidPostill Could you care to detail a little bit please? Because these powerline-phone adapters (https://www.amazon.co.uk/RTX-WIRELESS-PHONEJACK-Phone-White/dp/B000NJQHL4) exist, I thought the principle would be the same. I would just have to adapt the jacks at both ends of my powerline-ethernet adapters...

Comment: @Ramhound I thought it was obvious that I needed to connect the phone line to wifi router because it carried the ADSL signal. Also, in this case it's in the same building. It's the powerline of my own apartment (edited the OP).

Comment: @cinico - I have a landline phone.  ADSL never even entered my mind.  Those adapters have absolutely nothing to do with PowerLine.  They communicate with themselves, powered by the socket you plug them in, by connecting one end with a source (hence the reason one of them has two plugs).  It looks like the communicate over 2.4 GHz (which is what DECT uses).  **It’s a fancy cordless phone base.**

Comment: Why are you willing to have a powerline adapter where your phone line is, but not the modem?  Phone jack > DSL modem > Powerline adapter.  Powerline adapter > Wi-Fi router.

Comment: @Jason Because it's basically in a hole, strongly degrading wifi reception

Comment: I think you're confusing the difference between a modem and a wi-fi router.

Comment: @Jason I am not. It jut happens that my router is also my ADSL modem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot do this. I will not go into the technical details of why this is impossible, given that [Mokubai ♦](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai)'s answer explains this very well.

I still felt it necessary to write an answer, because this is a classic XY problem. You have a problem, came up with a solution, need help with that solution and ask here, but your solution is not the best way to solve the problem.

I identified your problem as follows: You want a WIFI or ethernet access at a place across your house but your internet is not entering at that location. (this is a common problem actually)

The obvious solution here (this is what everyone does) is place the ADSL modem/router where the internet comes in, and get the data (ethernet) signal across the house from there. This can be done using a Powerline adapter.

It would not be the best and most reliable option though. An ethernet cable is definitely the best option. A wifi repeater could also work but it will reduce the speeds. A PowerLine Adapter will also work, but is known to require a reset every once in a while.

Lets assume you go for the Powerline adapters option, given that that was included in your question and you have them, you would need something at the other end (in your livingroom/bedroom/etc) to be able to give one or more devices access to the internet. If you only use one or more pc's, you can use ethernet cables to with one or more powerline adapters to create your network. If you want wifi support, you will need a wifi capable broadcaster, such as an access point or a wifi-router. A wifi router would allow 3 ethernet ports and wifi access in your room with just one set of powerline adapters and give you great expandability. I mention 3 ethernet ports, not 4, because I would plugin the ethernet cable in one of the LAN ports, not the WAN port. This will ensure that the modem/router creates the whole network, and you won't have to make port forwardings twice.

Comment: You understood my question/problem perfectly. Great answer, thank you. Do you know if I connect a wifi repeater through ethernet (from powerline adapter B) if this minimizes the loss of speed, compared with using an wifi repeater to receive/transmit everything through wifi?

Comment: Yes, this will not reduce the speed. The problem with a wifi-repeater is that it needs 2 channels through the air to transmit the same data as it communicates with the other wifi point, this effectively cuts the speed in half, not counting any reception issues. Powerline does not suffer from this at all, but is known to be a bit unstable and requires a reset every once in a while.

Comment: Between us we answer both sides of the problem. I would be happy if you wanted to incorporate or improve on my slightly poorly worded answer and put it into your own. I have added to my answer to try and get the point over better but feel it is lacking somewhat while yours gets to the core issue and provides actual solutions. I am a little focused on "why not" rather than "what you can do". If they were merged then I could delete my answer. I have already upvoted your answer as it is more directly helpful than my own.

Comment: @Mokubai I see where you getting at. I'm just not sure how to incorporate part of your answer into mine. I think your answer is a great answer actually so I personally would say: keep them both on. Your answer is definitely not wrong and it is a great source for people to learn from.

Comment: @cinico I just reread your question and I misunderstood you the first time. A wifi repeater has no Ethernet input and will just copy an existing wifi, boosting its range so to speak. You can't plug it into a powerline adapter. A Wifi Access Point is almost the same, but instead of boosting an existing wifi signal, it creates a new one from an Ethernet port. You connect the ethernet port to the powerline adapter in your case.

Comment: @LPchip you're right. I was actually referring to these wifi repeaters that have an ethernet socket so that they can act as AP. So, not as repeaters. Still, your first answer clarified my doubt

Comment: @cinico, the description of PowerLine in this answer is biased by the author. I have used PowerLine for well over a year, no resets needed and with consistent 150/70 Mbit speeds(with 300/70 Mbit provided by our ISP), very stable, both for gaming and streaming. Both our experiences are obviously not enough to prove anything, but if you have a way to test it for a while, you might find that it works well for you too.

Comment: @cinico It is actually entirely possible that modern Wi-Fi (802.11ac/ax) can provide both a much faster and more reliable backhaul than powerline (HomePlug). Depends on the distances involved, the house layout (for Wi-Fi), the electrical circuits (for HomePlug), etc..

Comment: @WilliamMariager my experiences tell me otherwise. I have used a powerline adapter myself and it ran fine for more than 7 months when I started to have weird timing issues that I could not explain. When I finally checked the powerline adapter, I noticed it had lights flashing. I resetted the connection and all was fine. Since I occasionally had problems which I later found out can be influenced by what electric devices are available in the house. I have had periods of many months without issues and sometimes one reset a month. For work, my boss has the very same experience.

Comment: @LPChip that's fine, I'm just adding my experience as well, so people can see that PowerLine can be a perfectly fine solution, contrary to what the answer suggests.

Comment: 2 notes.(1) I have also used several powerline adapters in 2 different apartments for years without a glitch. (2) not sure from the answer but for around €30 you can get a WiFi extender which serves as a simple ap which bridges your Ethernet to WiFi

Comment: You can buy powerline adapters that have built-in WiFi at the remote end. That means you won't need a separate router there.

Comment: I'm stuck using two TP-Link 500Mbs adapters here because the WiFi adapter on my notebook is dead and I can't run a cable from the gateway to where I use my notebook. It works fine, but nowhere near as fast as my gateway. I do find that I have to drop the connection and restart it a number of times a week. That might be the powerline units. (I run Linux and USB WiFi adapters that work are slower.)

Answer (score 14):

Powerline adaptors take *data*, as in ethernet packets, and convert them to an analogue/digital signal that can be transmitted over electrical wiring.

Your phone line ADSL works in the opposite direction. It is an analogue signal carrier encapsulating a digital signal that needs your modem to decode.

You are effectively wanting the powerline adaptor to do analogue-to-analogue conversion rather than digital to analogue.  They are not analogue to analogue converters. This will not work.

Telephone extension cables are [cheap](https://www.screwfix.com/p/telephone-extension-kit-10m/4911x). There are [telephone over powerline](https://www.amazon.co.uk/One-All-Wireless-Telephone-Extender/dp/B0007D8804) adaptors, but I would expect them to be voice-only. ADSL uses a lot of high frequency signals that will probably be lost by any such adaptor.

Get an extension cable in order to move your telephone point.

---

The other problem would be that you would be effectively putting your phone signal onto the local power grid. While some power filtering may happen at the power inlet to your home it may be effectively a direct connection and could allow anyone with a similar device to effectively steal or otherwise mess with your internet connection.

---

To explain a little more [VDSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSL) (and ADSL) uses a complex set of transmitters and receivers working together. They effectively inject multiple signals on to a data line to achieve what is a large number of relatively small individual bandwidth signals. Any device to retransmit these signals would have to understand the types of signal expected, the frequencies and magnitudes and so on as they need to deconstruct and reconstruct them.

Powerline adaptors *might* function in a similar way, but due to them being proprietary and only intended to be used with another identical device, are under no constraints to be interoperable with major telephone devices. They don't care about ADSL or VDSL or any other transmission scheme except their own. As such they tend to make up their own scheme and could well not be sensitive enough or have enough bandwidth at specific frequencies to be compatible even if they accepted analogue signals on both sides.

Powerline adaptors are also (generally) actual intelligent network devices. They don't convert the electrical signals underlying the Ethernet protocol to "audio on the line" but instead accept Ethernet data packets and convert those instead. Otherwise there would be a lot of unnecessary noise on your powerline, even when nothing was being transmitted between devices on your network. Think of Powerline devices as similar to Wifi devices, except that their signals get pushed onto (coupled onto) your electrical wiring.

As a result the only device guaranteed to be able to convert ADSL to powerline would be an ADSL-to-powerline adaptor and those don't appear to be that common a thing, probably due to there being a lot of standards requiring support to ensure compatibility.

Most solutions I can find are along the lines of the answer posted by [LPChip](https://superuser.com/a/1517403/19943): use a proper ADSL modem where you can, then an Ethernet-to-Powerline adaptor or other solutions.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed to know. I didn't know that these adapters worked with data packets. I thought that would simply directly transmit a (digital) signal. For that reason, I thought that because the difference between digital and analog is basically the shape of the signal (squared vs sine), maybe the frequency of the signal was not that different between ethernet and phone, and then it could work... I was trying to avoid phone extension cords because of all the work to lay it around the walls compared with this simple potential solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @cinico a digital signal vs analog signal is not just sine vs square waveform. It will look like that, but the difference is significant. A digital signal is a set of instructions on how to recreate the analog signal. By standardizing the digital signal, it is possible to remove a lot of data from the digital signal as such that more data can be fitted at a place such that higher speeds are possible or lower bandwidth is utilized. Look at it from a .wav file vs .mp3 file perspective. If you want more info, search on you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2OPnrgb0pY

Comment: @LPChip I know the difference. I mean for transmission purposes (not for processing) the only difference could only be the waveform and the (range of) frequency(ies).

Comment: @cinico In terms of electricity, analog vs digital is very different too. In electricity, analog is a constant flow of electricity where its intensity fades in and out creating a waveform. In digital signals, these are pulses of on and off being fired at a specific interval. The very first series of pulses in a digital signal is the handshake, which is meant to establish that communication is possible. Analog does not handshake, thus a digital input will never understand an analog output.

Comment: @cinico For transmission purposes, the "only" difference of waveform and frequencies is actually a massive one that ought not be trivialized--even if I had an analog modulator that upconverted some baseband analog signal and injected it onto power lines, I'd still be hitting tons of issues. This is where the phone-over-powerline issue comes up, since it has a lowpass characteristic which is fundamentally incompatible with ADSL.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica - ζ-- I was not trivializing, just focusing on differences. As I said, before knowing that the adapters actually transmit packets of data, and not the direct signal, my hope was that it would work because the frequencies could be similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an older house, it *may* have phone jacks in multiple rooms. In that case, you will have a phone connection at the far side of the house, and you can plug your DSL modem in there.

Comment: Older house? Newer houses are likely to have more jacks; jacks weren't even common in older houses as they tended to be 4-prong or hardwired.

Comment: @InterLinked My mom's house was built in 1952 — 70 years ago — and had phone jacks in the living room, dining room, and two bedrooms. Granted, they were 4-prong jacks rather than modern RJ11 jacks, but converting them to RJ11 only takes a few minutes.

Comment: Right, I should've specified "modular". I think 4-prong jacks would have been most common at that time, or hardwired. Portable phones weren't common until the late 50s, and modular not until the 70s, so modular jacks are more common in homes from the last 30-40 years